# How to redirect back to a POST route in Laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes, return

I've a price range search slider. Which is working for finding price between a range. It's working fine. If I set a range & press Search button it return the search result. But I'm facing a problem here. I've some product in "price-range-search". I can check details from here. But when I try to "add-to-cart" faced a problem.

In my *add-to-cart* Route having a function named *add_to_cart* which add the product to the cart & return back to the previous page from where it came.

In this situation I'm facing a problem "MethodNotAllowedHTTPException" as it's a POST Route.

Note:my *add_to_cart* function is working properly. But facing problem while `return redirect()->back();`

I also try `return redirect()->back()->withInput();`

it also feeding me the same errors.

Any Idea to get Solution?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can you show code of your two routes and controller methods?

Comment: What is your route method? Post? Can you please post the code for your route & controller

Comment: price-range-search Route:-

`Route::post('/price-range-search', 'WelcomeController@price_range_search');`

add-to-cart Route:-

`Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/add-to-cart/{id}', 'CartController@add_to_cart');`

Answer (score 0):

This happen just from price-range-search POST Controller to add-to-cart GET Controller
and add-to-cart GET Controller method just return back() to the page where from request came. In this case the problem arise. It's unable to return back() to the post controller. So what is the possible solution!

price-range-search Route:-
`Route::post('/price-range-search', 'WelcomeController@price_range_search');`

add-to-cart Route:-
`Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/add-to-cart/{id}', 'CartController@add_to_cart');`

[checkRoutesimageshere:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDeS9.jpg)

price_range_search Controller Function:-
`

```
public function price_range_search(Request $request)
{
    $data = array();
    $data['price_range'] = $request->input('price_range');
    // echo $data['price_range'];
    $min_max = explode(',', $data['price_range']);
    $min = $min_max[0];
    $max = $min_max[1];

    $search_result = DB::table('tbl_product')
            ->whereBetween('product_price', array($min, $max))
            ->orderBy('product_id', 'desc')
            ->get();

    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($search_result);
    // exit();

    $search_content = view('pages.search')
                    ->with('min', $min)
                    ->with('max', $max)
                    ->with('search_result', $search_result);

    return view('index')
                    ->with('content', $search_content);
}
```

[img of price_range_search Controller Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maNyp.jpg)

add-to-cart Route Controller Function:-

public function add_to_cart($id, Request $request) {

```
    $product_info = DB::table('tbl_product')
            ->where('product_id', $id)
            ->first();

    $data['id'] = $product_info->product_id;
    $data['name'] = $product_info->product_name;
    $data['price'] = $product_info->product_price;

    $qty = $request->product_quantity;
    if ($qty > 1) {
        $data['qty'] = $qty;
    } else {
        $data['qty'] = 1;
    }

    $data['options'] = array('image' => $product_info->product_image);

    Cart::add($data);
    Session::put('message', ' Your Cart Item(s) are Updated! ');

    // return back()->send();
    return redirect()->back()->withInput(Input::all());
    // return Redirect::to('/show-cart');
}
```

`
[img of add-to-cart Controller Function:-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gda6d.jpg)

Note: This happen just from price-range-search POST Controller to add-to-cart GET Controller and add-to-cart GET Controller method just return back() to the page where from request came. In this case the problem arise. It's unable to return back() to the post controller. So what is the possible solution!

This is actually not the answer. But @rits & @Mohamed Ahmed both want to see the two routes and controller methods code. But in comment unable to supply information that's why postin as answer. Sorry for that.